# Composite Primary Key is displaying as null

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am implementing a composite primary key made up of 3 other values. I have created the table, and inserted data in all other fields. Am I correct to assume that I don't need to provide values for the composite pk as its using other values to create itself? Here are my CREATE and INSERT scripts to help...

```
CREATE TABLE representation
(
   representation_id   NUMBER (4),
   reference_id        NUMBER (4),
   case_id             NUMBER (4),
   barrister_id        NUMBER (2),
   CONSTRAINT representation_case_id_fk FOREIGN KEY
      (case_id)
       REFERENCES CASE (case_id),
   CONSTRAINT representation_barrister_id_fk FOREIGN KEY
      (barrister_id)
       REFERENCES barrister (barrister_id),
   CONSTRAINT representation_pk PRIMARY KEY
      (reference_id, case_id, barrister_id)
);

INSERT INTO representation (reference_id, case_id, barrister_id)
     VALUES (sq_representation_reference.NEXTVAL, '0', '5');
```

Comment: What is the problem? Did you expect *representation_id* to get a value?

Comment: Yes, you have to populate values into your primary key fields. Best of luck.

Comment: @trincot I wasn't "expecting" it to... I wasn't sure what the result would be, I wasn't sure whether it would be populated or not. I thought I needed to populate it myself - which makes sense. Just wanted to make sure. Thanks though

Comment: "Composite Primary Key is displaying as null." No evidence given of that.For the composite primary key to be null, you'd need to show that `reference_id`, `case_id`, and/or `barrister_id` are null. `Representation_id` is not set to be a key of any type in the DDL you posted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no instruction here for Oracle to give *representation_id* a value. Although the name of that field is very suggestive as being a unique identifier, there is nothing actually making it that, nor giving it a value.

You'll have to insert a value yourself. This you can do in several ways, like:

- define a default value for it (but this would give it the same value every time), or
- include the name and value in your `INSERT` statement, or
- write an `ON INSERT` trigger in which you define the value of this field via some formula based on the other three, or get it from a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Your composite primary key comprises three columns:

```
CONSTRAINT representation_pk PRIMARY KEY
  (reference_id, case_id, barrister_id)
```

Your insert statement succeeds because those are the three columns you populate:

```
INSERT INTO representation (reference_id, case_id, barrister_id)
```

Nothing happens with REFERENCE_ID because it's an optional column:

```
SQL> desc representation
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 REPRESENTATION_ID                                  NUMBER(4)
 REFERENCE_ID                              NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 CASE_ID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 BARRISTER_ID                              NOT NULL NUMBER(2)

SQL>
```

(Oracle makes the primary columns mandatory even though you didn't explicitly  specify the NOT NULL constraints.)